# Resubscribe but don't cache errors and completion

Tags: rx-java

I have an `Observable` that does some long running tasks once subscribed to. At the end it emits a `Boolean` that represents if it succeeded.

What I want to archive is that the task keeps running even when unsubscribed so it can finish it's work. I want to be able to re-subscribe to it so it does not have to start from scratch.
However if it has completed by `onCompletion` or `onError` I want to subscribe to it from scratch so I do not pick up an old or error state.

I first thought the obvious solution would be to use `Observable.cache()` but that does not work as it also caches errors.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this particular case can be solved with just RxJava operators because of the half-publish half-refCount requirement. Here is how I'd do it:

```
AtomicReference<AsyncSubject<Boolean>> result = new AtomicReference<>();

Observable<Boolean> source = Observable.just(1)
        .doOnSubscribe(() -> System.out.println("Source subscribed to"))
        .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).map(v -> true);

Observable<Boolean> o = Observable.defer(() -> {
    for (;;) {
        AsyncSubject<Boolean> s = result.get();
        if (s == null || s.hasCompleted() || s.hasThrowable()) {
            AsyncSubject<Boolean> s2 = AsyncSubject.create();
            if (result.compareAndSet(s, s2)) {
                source.subscribe(s2);
                return s2;
            }
            continue;
        }
        return s;
    }
});

System.out.println("-- First round");
o.subscribe(System.out::println);
o.subscribe(System.out::println);

Thread.sleep(1100);

System.out.println("-- Second round");
o.subscribe(System.out::println);
o.subscribe(System.out::println);

Thread.sleep(1100);
```

By using an atomic reference, `AsyncSubject` and `defer`, I publish the result of the source Observable through the subject but also make sure a completed subject will trigger a new subscription.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Observable.retry().cache()` to retry on errors.

Comment: But then it wouldn't restart on subscription if finished once.

Comment: Looks like you need `repeat` + `retry`?

Comment: And where in the chain do I put repeat?

Comment: Observable.repeat().retry()?